# docker RUN: how to export env variable from script to use in same RUN command later?

Tags: docker

I need to write some complex command chain in RUN, during which i'd like to manipulate with environment variables from shell script.

I'd tried this approach

`RUN echo 'export TEST=test' > /srv/test.sh && chmod 777 /srv/test.sh && /srv/test.sh && env`

but with no success: `env` shows no `TEST` variable.

I suppose we can do something like this

`RUN export $(script.sh)` and echo (not export) variables in in `script.sh`, but it's not so direct and is kind of workaround. Are there better approach?

What I'd like to achieve is to build image behind corporate proxy. It's not solved with just setting correct `http_proxy`, because i.e. sbt can not install itself correctly behind proxy with authentication. So I need to install some helper proxy inside docker image, generate config for it from `http_proxy`, run helper proxy and then export new `http_proxy`. All this stuff is better to put into script, so it can be used in different layers and also in `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: Care to explain what are you actually trying to achieve? And why do you need to “chain” lots of commands in a single run? But please, do it in your question not in comments.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What exactly do you want to do?  By the way, if you *source* the script then what you wrote would work.  The way you have it listed the variable is only visible to the shell created by the execution of /srv/test.sh

Comment: `source` does not work during docker build
`RUN echo 'export TEST=test' > /srv/test.sh && source /srv/test.sh && env`
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Comment: try `.  /srv/test.sh` (a dot instad of `source`). `source` is supported by bash not /bin/sh

Comment: . (dot) instead source works! Thanks!